Azure Traffic Balancing Between Backends with Different Route Prefixes
We are migrating hosting infrastructure from a system which used subdomains to differentiate between different microservices to one which uses route prefixes. For example the "root" of our microservice could be hit like this on the old infrastructure:
https://my-service.legacyhosting.com/
and like this on the new infrastructure:
https://api.modernhosting.com/my-service
We would like to setup something in Azure in front of both of these that can route a percentage of traffic to the new hosting and the remaining traffic to the old hosting.
In other words, we want to be able to slowly migrate traffic over to the new infrastructure. But we've run into problems because of the difference in route prefix between these two.
                                  /--- 25% ---> https://my-service.legacyhosting.com/*
https://some.thing.in.azure/* ---|
                                  \--- 75% ---> https://api.modernhosting.com/my-service/*

My first thought was to use Front Door, however this does not work (Classic or Premium) because two backends in the same pool (legacy) or origin group (premium) cannot have different route prefixes.
My next thought was to use Traffic Manager, but it has the same limitation.
I'm going to start investigating Azure Load Balancers and App Gateways next, but I wanted to see if anyone has solved this problem before or has any advice. It seems like this would be a common scenario with an easy solution, but I can't seem to find anything on it after extensive googling.

You can use Nested Traffic Manager, follow the MS DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles.

Sorry, I think you need to read the prompt a bit better. The problem is about routing to two different backends with different route prefixes. Traffic Manager uses DNS to route traffic and so no solution involving Traffic Manager will work (because DNS only cares about hostname, not the path). I mentioned my attempts to use both FrontDoor and Traffic Manager in the latter half of the question and why they don't work.

We ended up utilizing multiple endpoints in a Premium FrontDoor, essentially acting like 2 front doors.
We made the first endpoint with a route of / and https://api.modernhosting.com/my-service/* as the only backend. This allows us to essentially "map" this new endpoint host (with no route prefix) to our desired backend with a route prefix.
We then made a second endpoint which has an Origin Group containing the first endpoint and https://my-service.legacyhosting.com/*, thus allowing us to direct traffic between the two.
I feel like this setup is a little gross, but it gets the job done. Since this is a temporary arrangement for us, I'm willing to live with it. Still, it would be nice to see Azure provide something that can handle this use case more gracefully.
